# Why won't my expression evaluate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax

I have defined a function first and then I need to integrate something to find the time (it's theoretical mechanics). I think I don't have any syntax issues but what am I doing not the way I should?

[image]
[image]

I've tried wrapping the expression in `Evaluate`, but it gives the same result.

In case somebody would like the code, here it is:

```
U[x_] := Subscript[U, 0]*Tan[α*x]^2

t = 
  (Sqrt[m/2])*
    Integrate[1/Sqrt[E - U[x_]] , 
      {x, 
       1/α*Log[(A - Sqrt[A*(A - Abs[E])]/Abs[E])], 
       1/α*Log[(A + Sqrt[A*(A - Abs[E])]/Abs[E])]}]
```

Comment: It may just be because Mathematica doesn't know a closed form for your integral. Also, do you mean to use `E` in your code as an arbitrary constant? `E` is the basis of natural logarithms in *Mathematica*. Don't use variables with uppercase names, especially single-letter ones, as you risk conflicts with built-ins like this one.

Comment: FWIW, `Integrate[1/Sqrt[a - b Tan[x]^2], x]` does return a proper (elementary!) closed form.

Comment: I see two issues: one major and one I don't know. Your definition of the function `U` is recursive, since `U` appears on both sides. Change the one on the left to lower-case or something else. The other is that in your definition of `t`, `U[t_]` should be `U[t]`. Finally, why do you have `Abs[E]`? `E` is by definition a positive number. I believe that `E` is supposed to be energy, but `E` is reserved for the number $e$ in *Mathematica*. In general, don't use upper case letters or capitalized words for user-defined functions and symbols.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `U` in the integration, you should just say `U[x]`, not `U[x_]`. You inadvertently left in the underscore pattern marker (a.k.a. Blank).

Comment: I changed it o U(x) still docent show anything.

Comment: Yeah, sorry to hear that. It was definitely a problem, and at least partly answered your question "what am I doing not the way I should", but I'm afraid I can't help beyond that.